# Measure low DOM absorbance values in a microplate reader. Is there a suitable deep well microplate with flat bottoms available?

Tags: organic-chemistry, spectrophotometry

I would like to use a microplate reader to measure the absorbance of dissolved organic matter (DOM), but the measured values are close to the lower detection limit. To overcome this, I thought of deep well plates as the pathlength is longer then. Nevertheless, I have not found any deep well plates with flat bottoms, which might be best for absorbance measurements. I want to avoid measuring in a photometer with 5 cm pathlength because the available amount of sample is limited and the microplate would need much less.

Does anybody have experience with similar problems?

Can anyone suggest a suitable microplate?

What is your opinion on the influence of the material?

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware of suitable microplates for this application.  Here are some alternative approaches.

#### 1. Low-volume quartz cuvettes.

There are quartz cuvettes in "micro" formats that may be suitable for you.  Mostly commonly they work with 1 cm pathlength.  The volume of the cells is controlled by the width of the non-optical dimension.  This can be made extremely small.

[One example I found](http://www.starnacells.com/d_cells_s/rect/T016.html) lists cuvettes that still have path lengths of 1 cm with total fill volumes as low as 15 μL.

#### 2. Sample concentration

Details depend heavily on the details of your DOM and application, but you could concentrate your samples and then use existing microplates.

#### 3. Longer measurement times.

Most plate readers (and cuvette-based spectrophotometers) let you control the number of "shots" or of the total amount of time a measurement of light intensity is integrated over.  You could crank this number up to get better sensitivity.